# Invalid Column Name Exception in EF4 when calling SaveChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, exception, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to Create a new Article, which looks like:

```
Article:
    ArticleID - int (primary key, auto-incr)
    Title - nvarchar(100)
    Text - text
    LastModified - Datetime
```

Controller code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateArticle(Article article)
    {
        try
        {
            article.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
            _siteDB.Articles.AddObject(article);
            _siteDB.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The inner exception is:

> {"Invalid column name 'Title'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Text'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LastModified'."}

Not sure why they'd be considered invalid.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your database and your EDM metadata are still in sync? I would suggest to *Update the Model from Database* just to make sure that your SSDL has the latest changes from the DB.

Comment: Yes, check your database and your Models match. Sometimes we define one model to start programming the interface, and we leave the Database tables unchanged, then when the DataContext is created, is all a mess and causes strange errors like this. I just solved it by reading this answer, my error showed when executing db.SaveChanges() was "invalid Quote_QuoteID", the reason was in database I just defined Quote.QuoteID, while in the Model class I had set all fields. I quick fixed by putting on comments my model properties, so they match the single Quote.QuoteID in database table.

Comment: The tricky part was, I was updating another Model (Deal, DealActivity), no related to Quotes, but I guess is when you commit changes using db.SaveChanges, the DataContext loads/validates the complete Model list and its structure agains the Database, then showed the weird error.